# Where did non NS5 robots get their updates from?

Tags: i-robot-2004

In *I, Robot*, one of the most important features of the new NS5 is their ability to download updates from USR daily.  Simple question then - where did the previous generations of robots get *their* updates from?  (This is assuming that they indeed received updates, which may be an incorrect assumption).  I'm looking for indications within the film, but out-of-film references are fine, but of course NO speculation!

Comment: Within the film, there's no evidence that the previous generations got any upgrades. Maybe they came with a cable, remember the times before iOS 4 and OTA upgrades.

Comment: @Kevin the question would then be where do they plug the robots into?

Comment: Into their iPhones, of course.

Comment: @Kevin I remember my flip-phone from 2005 had OTA upgrades...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Asimov robot universe robots were leased, never sold, and as such U.S. Robots and Mechanical Men was responsible for their continued maintenance.  Presumably you took the robot to an authorized service center just as you would an automobile under warranty.  The robot would get any firmware updates then.  Or, since an NS4 is capable of finding its own way around, maybe the robot goes off to get itself serviced at regular intervals unless otherwise instructed.

Comment: Upvoted, but note that the *I, Robot* film does not explicitly take place in Asimov's robot universe.  Rather, it's a mashup of elements from several stories which *are* set in that universe.